# Doing a SELECT and UPDATE simultaneously IF a condition is met in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a checkout system. I have 3 tables, one which holds the products and one which holds the user's cart and one which holds the completed orders.

products

```
product_id  |  product_name  | stock  |  unit_price
1           |  item1         | 10     |  40
2           |  item2         | 5      |  30
3           |  item3         | 4      |  29
```

cart

```
user_id  |  product_id  |  quantity
1        |  1           |  4
1        |  2           |  6
```

completed orders

```
user_id  |  product_id  |  quantity
1        |  3           |  2
```

What I'm trying to do is do a SELECT in the PRODUCTS and check if the Stock is greater than the quantity from the user's cart. If this is true, then it decreases the Stock count directly in the MYSQL query.

Now the issue I'm having is, I don't know if this is possible. I can do it in PHP but it will take quite a few iterations, which I want to avoid in case it's not too optimized.

I searched around and I found a partial solution here: [MySQL - SELECT then UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590256/mysql-select-then-update/24590333)

However, I don't know how to include the IF in it.

Comment: I guess it could be done by using MySQL `IF`, but the question is *should* it be done. There is nothing wrong with running two queries, especially since running one of them is optional. You may be optimizing prematurely. Plus - if you merge it all into one conditional update, you won't have feedback if the value actually updated or the update was prevented (seems like a valuable piece of information to display to a customer).

Comment: Do you want to update if *all* stock is greater than (or equal?) the quantity in the cart or *any* stock?

Comment: @Nick all stock. As you see in this example, I demonstrated a case where this can't happen, so I'm not sure if this will make sense to do with MySQL or if I have to use PHP and first iterate through the cart, then do a select on each cart item to check the stock and hold a boolean, finally do an update in the products table if all the stocks are actually greater, then clear cart. It seems overly complex in PHP. I was wondering if there is a way to do this quicker with MySQL. (Or even if this makes sense)

Comment: @El_Vanja You asked a good question, should it? See my comment above to Nick. I'm  concerned about the fact of what happens if 2 users click checkout at almost the same time.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick MySQL v8.0.19 , PHP 7.3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in MySQL8 in one query, using a `CTE` to compute whether all the stock in a cart can be satisfied and then updating `products` only if it can:

```
WITH cart_balance_ok AS (
  SELECT c.user_id, 
         MIN(p.stock >= c.quantity) AS cart_ok
  FROM cart c 
  JOIN products p ON p.product_id = c.product_id
  GROUP BY c.user_id
)
UPDATE products p
JOIN cart c ON c.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN cart_balance_ok cb ON cb.user_id = c.user_id AND cb.cart_ok = 1
SET p.stock = p.stock - c.quantity
```

Demo showing no changes because not enough stock [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bk7xzvJhvjRwo7FyFrkZ2R/0). Demo showing changes to `products` where there is enough stock [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bk7xzvJhvjRwo7FyFrkZ2R/1).

You should then be able to use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to determine if the update took place.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! I combined it with https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php instead. However, the query does not run on phpmyadmin, any idea why it does not recognize WITH there?

Comment: @nTuply that's weird, I don't know why it wouldn't run on phpMyAdmin - is it possible you're running a different version of MySQL when you connect with that.

Comment: It seems there is a bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799157/use-a-cte-to-update-or-delete-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @order_quantity:=quantity FROM CART WHERE product_id=1;

    UPDATE products 
    SET stock = CASE WHEN @order_quantity<=stock THEN stock-@order_quantity ELSE stock END
    WHERE product_id=1;

    COMMIT;
```

[Here is fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fVaennMSLKwmwJtdWSvkEn/0) The cart had 10 products, stock had 20, 10 is left after update. Only if its <=.